# Stop AWS EC2 if no input requests in FastAPI after a specific time

Tags: python, fastapi

I have AWS EC2 Windows Server, and I'm running FastAPI on uvicorn. Is there a good way to shutdown Windows Server if there is no input requests in FastAPI from clients after e.g. 30 minutes?
I'm using Python 3.9.7.

Comment: You could explore on ``lambda services``, instead of using EC2 instance.

Comment: lambda is not suitable for my tasks

Comment: Maybe your app could set/reset a 30 minute timer after each inbound request. If the timer pops then shutdown the EC2 instance that the app is running on (using either native Windows features or the EC2 StopInstances API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to a file the last time a request is made in your `FastAPI` server. Then, using a `cronjob` or similar tool, you can check file last line, compare that time with current time and shutdown the server when needed. Kind of a hackish solution anyway because it halts the server without doing any kind of tide-up work.

Example:

FastAPI code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from time import time

app = FastAPI()

def save_req_time():
    with open("./req_time.txt", "a") as fle:
        fle.write(f"{time()}\n")


@app.get("/")
async def root():
   save_req_time()
   return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Shutdown script (Powershell)
This script reads last request time, checks time delta, and shutdown the server if necessary.

[Windows server shutdown command docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)

```
$current_time = [int64](Get-Date -UFormat %s)

Get-Content .\req_time.txt -Tail 1 -Wait | ForEach-Object {

    If ([int64]($_) - $current_time -ge 1800) { 

        shutdown
    
    }

}
```

Schedule Shutdown job (powershell)
Here you schedule the shutdown script to run every minute.

[Windows scheduled task docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute './shutdown_script.ps1'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger `
     -Daily -At 0am `
     -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1) `
     -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days 1)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "shutdown_fastapi"
```

For a more professional (yet complex) solution you can take a look to this python library: [RQ](https://python-rq.org/) to schedule background jobs that could make the check suggested here avoiding the use of powershell scripts and task scheduler.